# Surveyor TD-339 engines - used on all US powered robotic landers?

Tags: curiosity, lander, surveyor-program

I've read that derivatives of the original [Thiokol TD-339](http://heroicrelics.org/info/surveyor/surveyor-vernier.html) model of [vernier engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_thruster) for the [Surveyor program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveyor_program) was reused in the [Viking program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_program), and seen a hint that [MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory) was using the same heritage design, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

What about the Mars landers [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)) or [InSight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSight)?

More info and photos: [1](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/space-propulsion-reaction-motors-td-339-surveyor-vernier-rocket-system-surveyor), [2](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/rocket-engine-liquid-fuel-surveyor-vernier-also-designated-td-339), [3](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/rocket-engine-liquid-fuel-surveyor-vernier-also-designated-td-339-0), [4](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/rocket-engine-vernier-surveyor-spacecraft)

[image]

Photo from [here](http://heroicrelics.org/info/surveyor/surveyor-vernier.html).

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding some links and a photo. Many/most readers of your question won't be so familliar with heritage engines and spacecraft history as you are, so these may help a few to learn more. Feel free to [roll back](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: Aerotech MR-80 seems to have been Viking and its direct descendant Aerojet MR-80B on MSL. Probably no link or direct lineage to TD-339 at all

Answer (score 3):

### No, the propellants have changed from bipropellant to solid or monopropellant.

I can't confirm the exact engines of Surveyor and Viking, and I'll take your word that they were TD-339.  [Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_program#Propulsion) used bipropellant.

[Pathfinder/Sojourner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Pathfinder#Entry,_descent_and_landing) use solid rocket engines.

[MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory#Powered_descent)(Curiosity) used monopropellant.

[MER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Exploration_Rover#Cruise_stage)(Spirit and Opportunity) used monopropellant.

[InSight](http://spaceflight101.com/insight/insight-spacecraft/) used monopropellant in twelve Aerojet Rocketdyne MR-107N and four Aerojet Rocketdyne MR-106 engines.  Neither looks like the TD-339:

[image: MR-107N]
<sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/sites/216/2018/03/1089505_orig.jpg))</sub>

[image: MR-106]
<sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/sites/216/2018/03/5021412_orig-512x275.png))</sub>

[Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)#Specifications) also used monopropellant in Aerojet brand engines.  Although I cannot find the model numbers, there are eight 22 N and twelve 300 N engines.